# How to solve a partial derivative $u = f(x,xy,xyz)$?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

here's the following:

$$u = f(x,xy,xyz)$$

I am pretty new to partial derivatives, so do not judge much, but whats big difference (in the solving), between for example

$$u = x^4 + y^4 -4x^2y^2$$

where we take it as $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}$ then as $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}$ and finally as $\frac{\partial{^2u}}{\partial{x}\partial{y}}$

and the second one?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Do you just want the partials you listed? What is "the second one"?

Comment: Yep, I wanted someone to show me the correct way (better full), to understand the idea

Comment: You have an answer to the question starting with the definition of $u$ on the fifth line, but you are probably asking something about $f$, which has a "$z$" in it and involves $x$ and $y$ in a tricky way. If that's the case we're confused because you haven't made clear how $f$ enters the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer the question *I think* you are asking.

Suppose 
$$
u = f(x,xy,xyz) .
$$

Then to find $\partial u / \partial x$ you must use the *chain rule*:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = f_1(x,xy,xyz)
+ yf_2(x,xy,xyz)
+ yzf_3(x,xy,xyz)
$$
where I've written $f_1$ for the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to its first variable, and so on.

If I'm correct you should be able to do the rest. It is ugly  but straightforward using the sum, product and chain rules:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y \partial x} & = 
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f_1(x,xy,xyz)
+ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} yf_2(x,xy,xyz)
+ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} yzf_3(x,xy,xyz) \\
&= xf_{21}(x,xy,xyz) + xzf_{31}(x,xy,xyz) \\
& \quad + f_2(x,xy,xyz) + y\left( xf_{22}(x,xy,xyz) + xzf_{32}(x,xy,xyz) \right)\\
& \quad + \text{and so on}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: got the idea, thanks! But how will for example second derivative look like then?

Comment: @M.Mass See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but here is how to compute the partial derivatives:

$$u = x^4+y^4-4x^2y^2$$

When taking the partial derivative with respect to a variable $x$, you differentiate as normal whilst treating other variables as constants.

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 4x^3-8y^2x$$

$$\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial y \partial x} = -16yx$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 4y^3-8x^2y$$

$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x\partial y} = -16yx = \frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial y \partial x}$$

Comment: Sorry if i was unclear, i just compared two functions by the way of solving, I have to solve the function from the title, of course.